# Is there a way to set spring property source without any new configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on old project which doesn't have src/main/resources instead the property file is in a different source folder and has to be loaded in current class without adding @configuration or any new configurations. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you do not explain in great detail the context in which you are operating.

When you write that the properties file is in another **source** folder, does that mean that it is part of the classpath (it should, if it resides in a source folder)?

What do you mean by 'into current class'? How are you currently interpreting the properties from the configuration file(s)?

Since you tagged the question with 'spring-boot': can I assume that this is a spring-boot project? If so, I recommend reading the following chapter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files

Maybe your problem can be solved purely configurationally.